# Invalid value for IMPORT (invalid substitution type)

Tags: mount, automount

On Ubuntu server 22.04 I'm geting next errors:

```
Jul 29 06:23:54 can1 systemd-udevd[384]: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-digitalocean-automount.rules:11 Invalid value "/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_MOUNT_DIR=$(mktemp -d -p /mnt .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX)'" for IMPORT (char 32: invalid substitution type), ignoring.
Jul 29 06:23:54 can1 systemd-udevd[384]: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-digitalocean-automount.rules:12 Invalid value "/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_SCRIPT=$(mktemp -t .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX.sh)'" for IMPORT (char 29: invalid substitution type), ignoring.
```

I checked what is written in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-digitalocean-automount.rules and I have found next lines (beside others):

```
# Create a temporary mountpoint and temporary location for the first-mount script.
IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_MOUNT_DIR=$(mktemp -d -p /mnt .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX)'"
IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_SCRIPT=$(mktemp -t .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX.sh)'"
```

What is wrong?

EDIT: Here is a content of 99-digitalocean-automount.rules file

```
# Only try to automount DO block volumes.
SUBSYSTEM!="block", GOTO="do_automount_end"
ENV{ID_VENDOR}!="DO", GOTO="do_automount_end"
ENV{ID_MODEL}!="Volume", GOTO="do_automount_end"
# Only automount on the "add" action.
ACTION!="add", GOTO="do_automount_end"
# Only try to automount filesystems we know about.
ENV{ID_FS_TYPE}!="ext4|xfs", GOTO="do_automount_end"

# Create a temporary mountpoint and temporary location for the first-mount script.
IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_MOUNT_DIR=$(mktemp -d -p /mnt .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX)'"
IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_SCRIPT=$(mktemp -t .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX.sh)'"

# Mount the volume at the temp mountpoint and copy the script off, then unmount.
RUN{program}+="/bin/mount -o ro /dev/%k %E{TMP_MOUNT_DIR}"
RUN{program}+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/cp %E{TMP_MOUNT_DIR}/.first-mount.sh %E{TMP_SCRIPT} || exit 0'"
RUN{program}+="/bin/umount %E{TMP_MOUNT_DIR}"
RUN{program}+="/bin/rmdir %E{TMP_MOUNT_DIR}"

# Run the first-mount script. If it didn't exist this will be a no-op.
RUN{program}+="/bin/sh %E{TMP_SCRIPT} '%E{ID_SERIAL}' '%E{ID_FS_TYPE}' '%E{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}' '%E{ID_FS_UUID}' '%E{ID_FS_LABEL}'"

# Clean up.
RUN{program}+="/bin/rm %E{TMP_SCRIPT}"

# Finally, try and mount the volume. On first mount this will fail, but that's
# OK because the volume was already mounted by the first-mount script.
RUN{program}+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/mount /dev/%k || exit 0'"

LABEL="do_automount_end"
```

Comment: Can you show all the preceding lines (1 - 10) in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-digitalocean-automount.rules?

Comment: Of course. I edit the question and add the content at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to use a double dollar-sign (`$$`) in your shell commands.  `udev` has "substitutions" indicated with a single dollar-sign, and `$$` is a substitution for `$`.

```
IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_MOUNT_DIR=$(mktemp -d -p /mnt .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX)'"
IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_SCRIPT=$(mktemp -t .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX.sh)'"
```

becomes

```
IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_MOUNT_DIR=$$(mktemp -d -p /mnt .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX)'"
IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_SCRIPT=$$(mktemp -t .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX.sh)'"
```

**links**

- [similar solution in a bug report for a different udev rule](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1740662)
- [substitution documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#%24%24)

Comment: I followed your advice and used double dollar-sign. After restart, I checked journalctl, but the same error still exists. I checked the file again and - believe it or not - there was again single dollar-sign. I tried again (in case I made a mistake), but the same happened again. On restart, something change the double dollar-sign to single and the error is logged.

Comment: It sounds like the file gets generated each boot.  You can try to find what is doing that. Maybe `grep -r -l -- digitalocean-automount /etc/*`.  It could be cloud-init, systemd, cron, or something else.

Comment: No results from this grep command. This problem appeared on a server on DigitaOcean after it was upgraded to 22.04 LTS.

Comment: I created a 22.04 "droplet" in DigitalOcean.  It looks like they have fixed the `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-digitalocean-automount.rules` file because it is slightly different and it now uses the double dollar-sign syntax.  The file appears to be generated by some `cloud-init` configuration setup for their images.  You can see the configuration that generates the file in `/var/lib/cloud/instance/vendor-data.txt`.

Comment: In my vendor-data.txt I found this: 
IMPORT{program}="/bin/sh -c 'echo TMP_MOUNT_DIR=\$(mktemp -d -p /mnt .do-first-mount-XXXXXXXXX)'"

Instead double dollar-sign, I have "backslash dollar-sign".